# Problem with add_post_meta() function in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, post-meta, update-post-meta

When a use it like this:

```php
add_post_meta($post_ID, 'Name', "Bob", true );
```

works fine, but when a store an string value inside a variable, for example:

```php
$name = "Bob";
add_post_meta($post_ID, 'Name', $name, true ); // <---- This doesn't work.
```

Some help please. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.

```
$name = "Bob"; 
update_post_meta($post_ID, 'Name', $name );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the problem still there. Let me explain better. I have a custom post with 3 custom fields, this fields are generated when the user save it as draft, the problems is that i need to fill them with values from other custom post, in this case the most recent one. In this case i can get the value without any problem, but when i use the add_post_meta function to insert the values through variables the fields appears empty, however when change the variables for simples strings like "Bob" or "Jake" its work fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
$latestVideo = wp_get_recent_posts(array(
    'numberposts' => 1,
    'post_type'   =>'video',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
));

$latestVideoWeek = get_post_meta( $latestVideo[0]["ID"], "Week", true);
$latestVideoDate = get_post_meta( $latestVideo[0]["ID"], "Date", true);

function meta_info_video( $post_ID ) {
    add_post_meta( $post_ID, 'Semana', $latestVideoWeek, true );
    add_post_meta( $post_ID, 'Fecha', $latestVideoDate, true );
    add_post_meta( $post_ID, 'URL', '0', true  );
}

add_action( 'draft_video', 'meta_info_video' );
```